# How to find out the reason a command/code was executed on Linux?

Tags: linux, process

I have a complex embedded Linux software running on a gentoo derivative, on which a certain piece of code gets executed regularly every ~84 minutes. Sweeping through the main code to find places where this code might get executed was unsuccessful, and `crontab` also seems no possible explanation.

My question: Is it possible, by modifying the code in question, to find out which other process/code/file/service started it in the first place? Are there some information in the `/proc` directory I can use? Or is it impossible to find out the process that executed the given code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chris' answer would work if the process is long-lived, and you have time to go inspect it, but if it's a short running command, it may be difficult to catch it while the process is still alive.

Another way you could approach this is to put a 'wrapper' around the program.

Lets say the program being called is `/usr/bin/someprog`.

- Move `/usr/bin/someprog` to `/usr/bin/someprog.orig`.
- Create `/usr/bin/someprog` as a script such as:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "My pid: $$" >> /tmp/someprog.log
ps -ef --forest >> /tmp/someprog.log
exec /usr/bin/someprog.orig
```

- And then `chmod a+x /usr/bin/someprog`

This will dump a process tree and put it in `/tmp/someprog.log`. You could then look at the tree and find what is spawning it.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're looking for the parent PID (PPID):

```
$ ps -o ppid -p 5743
 PPID
  219
```

Since you also mentioned that you have `/proc`:

```
$ awk '{ print $4 }' /proc/5743/stat
219
```